# Radial profile from a Cartesian plot

Tags: normal-distribution, graphing-functions

I'd like to calculate a radial profile of a 2D Gaussian.

[image: 2D-Plot]

it should be a half of a Gaussian, maximum of about 3000 at $R=0$.

If I plot radial positions $\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \right)$ of every point, i get second distribution:

[image: rad-uncorrelated]

Is weighting with $\tfrac{1}{R}$ correct (picture below)? Should it also be weighted with integral area of the initial Gaussian?

[image: rad-cor]

Comment: Migrating to math, because this question explicitly asks for "a mathematical reason" in a situation not especially statistical in nature.  (It appears to be asking why the area element in polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$ equals $r dr d\theta$ and not $dr d\theta$.)

Comment: I am aware of infinitesimal polar area, I am only asking about verification/falsification - radial plot is seemingly of wrong magnitude as well

Comment: It would help to explain how you are computing these plots.  For instance, the middle one clearly does not plot the radial function divided by $R$ (because that would have a positive vertical asymptote at zero).  It appears instead to be *integrating* the density along the angular coordinate (and then "weighting" by $1/R$).

Comment: I'm guessing what you have is a large number of *samples* from a 2D Gaussian, and the figures you have shown are *histograms*, is that correct?

Comment: yes, histograms are derived from the 2D Gaussian

Comment: @troyaner: The first figure is also a two-dimensional histogram, yes? (P.S. It would be nice if you included "@Rahul" in your comment replies to me, so that I get notified of them. You always get notified of comments on your own question.)

Comment: @Rahul Narain: yes, it is a histogram of ~1e7 independently sampled Gaussian pairs. (thx for the @-tipp!)

Comment: $e^{- {(x^2+y^2)\over 2 \sigma^2}}dx dy = e^{-{r^2 \over 2 \sigma^2}} r dr d \theta$?